# What form does $\mathcal{B} = \{\{a\} \times (b,c) \subset \mathbb{R}^2|a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$ take? Explanation of topologies in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Say we have $\mathcal{B} = \{\{a\} \times (b,c) \subset \mathbb{R}^2|a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

The issue I'm having is visualizing what $\mathcal{B}$ looks like. I'm familiar with bases in $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't understand the form here. We have a set element $\{a\}$ crossed with an interval $(b,c)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Is it a circle? A rectangle?

This is almost embarrassingly basic, but the math symbology is really throwing me off, having never worked with topology beyond 1D before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is what it literally is.  An element of $A \times B$ is an ordered pair $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  So an element of $\{a\} \times (b,c)$ is an ordered pair $(a,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ where $y \in (b,c)$.  It is therefore a vertical open line segment that runs from the point $(a,b)$ to the point $(a,c)$.  Thus $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of all such open vertical line segments.  (The big potential place for confusion here is confounding an ordered pair with an open interval, since it is the same notation.)

Comment: That notational similarity was the thing throwing me off. Thank you.